# C++: Randomly repeated Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have problem running my program under Linux (*CentOS*). Code has no memory leaks. From time to time, program crashes with `"Segmentation fault"`. I have added control outputs to my code and when it crashes, program is executing every time the same code (which is correct, just load data from config file, that is there unchanged all the time). If I run program immideatly again, no crash `"Segmentation fault"` occurs and program runs just fine.

**EDIT:**

My Config file reader. [INIHandler.cpp](http://pastebin.com/RK2uHcwS)

From those library, I call

```
IniHandler ini(mapInfoName);

MyStringAnsi mapFileName = ini.ReadString("global", "map_file");
this->mapWidth = ini.ReadInt("global", "map_width");
this->minX = ini.ReadFloat("global", "minX");
```

**EDIT 2**

Code above is OK. I found out, that error occurs somewhere in this code:

```
std::vector<MyStringAnsi> inputFiles;
MyStringAnsi mapFile = "";
MyStringAnsi output = "";
MyStringAnsi coordinatesDataFileName = "";
MyStringAnsi outputCache = "";
MyStringAnsi type = "data";

for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    if ((argv[i][0] == '-') && (argv[i][1] == 'm'))
    {
        mapFile = argv[i + 1];
    }

    if ((argv[i][0] == '-') && (argv[i][1] == 'd'))
    {
        inputFiles.push_back(argv[i + 1]);
    }

    if ((argv[i][0] == '-') && (argv[i][1] == 'o'))
    {
        output = argv[i + 1];
    }

    if ((argv[i][0] == '-') && (argv[i][1] == 'f'))
    {
        coordinatesDataFileName = argv[i + 1];
    }

    if ((argv[i][0] == '-') && (argv[i][1] == 'c'))
    {
        outputCache = argv[i + 1];
    }

    if ((argv[i][0] == '-') && (argv[i][1] == 't'))
    {
        type = argv[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the config loading code please?

Comment: We cannot help without code.  If you just want advice then it would be "use a debugger".

Comment: @simonc Added code for ini parser

Comment: What does the stack trace say?

Comment: @Vijay I dont have stack trace. Error occurs in production build and is random. I can get it repeated, when I want :/

Comment: I think you have an error here:

    void IniHandler::Load(char * memory)
    {
            MyStringAnsi tmp = memory; //will be freed twice mb?

Could you post MyStringAnsi code?

Comment: Have you tried valgrind btw?

Comment: @kw I am using leak detector in Visual Studio (my program is written as multiplatform)

Comment: @Martin Perry, ok, i didn't say it is leak error though, seems like you have undefined behaviour, the only reason i think is new/delete error...

Comment: The code looks pretty good to me (although there seems alot of it to perform the task at hand).  I do wonder what would happen if you supplied a non-existent `section` to `IniHandler::KeyExist()` though...

Comment: @trojanfoe Eh.. missing section should be checked, thats bug :-) But it doesnt cause SegFault, because "ini" file is still unchanged and it wordks fine 90% of time.

Comment: No it doesn't.  I don't see the seg fault however.  Are you sure it's in this piece of code?

Comment: @trojanfoe I have added printfs and from start of program utill first printf, only this runs (plus class instance creation with new and some assignments of number values to variables).

Comment: You're going to need to reproduce the problem in debug mode within a debugger to have any chance of finding the issue.  Whack-up the memory management debugging (i.e. `CrtXXX()` under Windows or use debug malloc under Linux) to help you track this down.

Comment: Not about your question, but in your code some strange at end ReadBool(): "if (tmp.Find("true")) return false;"

Comment: @user1837009 Is right.  The code should be `return tmp == "true" || tmp == "yes" || tmp == "1";` or some such.